# Dialog box appear

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

I'm using decode for my query but when every time I run my query, there's a two dialog box appeared and need to input some number in those dialog box before to see the result. What should I need to remove it?

Please help me.

Thank you.

Here's some of my query..

```
  SELECT (CODE_SALESROOM) POS_ID
   ,DECODE(CODE_SALESROOM, '60001', 'ABM SYSTEM'
                          ,'50001', 'Acenet Unlimited Business Computer'
                          ,'40002', 'RL My Phone - Robinsons Galleria') AS POS_NAME
  FROM OWNER_DWH.DC_SALESROOM
  WHERE CODE_SALESROOM NOT IN ('XAP', 'XNA', '10001')
```

Comment: Is there an ampersand '&' anywhere in your query? If so, replace it like this - &' || '.

Comment: 'Some of' your query might not be enough; what is the mesage in the dialog box? Sounds like you have something in your query with an ampersand (`&`) and it's prompting for a substitution variable?

Comment: Your right Mikhail and Alex Poole, i remove ampersand and replace with '||'. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you're being prompted for [substitution variables](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_five.htm#CACIFHGB), because part of your query has somethling like `and col = 'AT&T'` - the ampersand is interpreted as a variable by default, and you're prompted for a value for `&T` (or whataver your actual value is interpreted as).

You can add [`set define off`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve017.htm) to your script to stop it looking for, and prompting for, a value when that is not what you want.

(The links are for SQL*Plus documentation, but [much of that applies to SQL Developer](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/doc.112/e12152/intro.htm#sthref192) as well; the documentation for that is a bit sparser),

Comment: where do i place set define off?

Comment: In your SQL script, right before your query; I usually 'run as script', but now I'm not sure quite how this works when you 'run statement'. Which isn't very helpful if that's what you're doing...